# View multiple active files in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tabs

In 2005, when I double-clicked on a file (be it header or source), it would open in a new tab. So, if I double-clicked on a header file and then two source files, there would be three tabs: one for each file. And the list of active files includes these three files.

I just installed VS 2008, and I've been trying to enable the same behavior, but I can't find the option anywhere. When I open my solution, the first header file opens up. Then when I try to click on the other source files, they replace that tab. And, my list of active files only contains one file: the most recent one I clicked on.

How do I enable multiple tabs/active files?

Comment: What do you mean by "header"?

Comment: edit: be it a header file or source file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to tools --> options --> environment --> documents

uncheck "reuse current document window"

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not the default behavior in VS 2008. I tried to replicate your problem, and got something which might be it. In Tools > Options > Documents, there is an option, "Reuse current document window if saved". It is unselected by default, if you select it you get something like what you are describing.